# Getting Bad Input with Python (Trinket)

Tags: python, syntax

I'm getting this bad input error whenever I try running this code, I don't think there's anything wrong with my code, I've indented correctly but I still get this stupid error.

```
firstRow = input()
secondRow = input()


r1 = input()
r2 = input()

if r1[0] == 'd' || r1[0] == 'D' || r2[0] == 'd' || r2[0] == 'D':
  if r1[1] == 'a' || r1[1] == 'A' || r2[1] == 'a' || r2[1] == 'A':
    if r1[2] == 'd' || r1[2] == 'D' || r2[2] == 'd' || r2[2] == 'D':
      print("yes")
    else print("no")
  else print("no")
else print("no")'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you're getting a syntax error then you should be able to look at where the caret in the error message is pointing to help debug the error. It appears you need to look at the operator you are using in the if statements and the syntax of the else statements where you may be missing colons.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the '||' with 'or' and add ':' after every 'else'.